# Camera error:Can not find the Camera after using a barcode scanning application

Tags: camera

I used a ZXing library to develop a barcode scanning application.When I used my Atrix2 and HTC EVO 3D to test the application.It works but it did not work with Alcatel ot986.It just did not response with black screen.After that I opened the default camera application,it showed that the phone could not find the camera.After restarting the phone,the camera is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you release the camera when you were done using it?

> Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other applications. Applications should release the camera immediately in onPause() (and re-open() it in onResume()).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: More food for thought...
Note: Starting with Android 4.0 (API level 14), the Camera.lock() and Camera.unlock() calls are managed for you automatically. [found here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)
May explain why it worked on phones running older OS versions